# « Qui parmi … vous aime » ou « qui parmi … vous aiment » ?

Tags: grammaire, accord, conjugaison

Je voulais savoir si on dit « Qui parmi … vous aime ? » ou bien « Qui parmi … vous aiment ? ». Je vote pour la première mais je ne suis pas sûr ? et pourquoi ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

« Qui aime/veut/... » est une tournure orale, qu'on utilise toujours au singulier et ce, même lorsqu'on peut attendre plusieurs candidats :

- *Qui prendra des pommes ?* (et non « *prennent* »)
- *Qui sait comment … ?* (et non « *savent* »)

Je suppose que cela sous-entend que chacun, parmi les concernés, se manifeste. Ainsi, c'est au singulier que le verbe est conjugué.

Answer (score 1):

La première me semble être en effet la bonne car le sujet "Qui parmi" référe à une 3e personne du singulier.

Answer (score 1):

> QUI : § II - Le Robert  
>     Pronom interrogatif désignant une personne (et rarement une chose).

La phrase étant interrogative, il faut donc utiliser *aime*,

> Qui parmi ... vous aime ?

Comment: Ton extrait du Robert dit lui-même « des deux nombres » !

Comment: @Édouard Le Robert  "I - pronom relatif des deux nombres , masculin ou féminin, désignant  *une* personne ou *une* chose" semble se référer à un emploi sans antécédent exprimé, comme dans la phrase interrogative